# SQL query - having expression > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I am working on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and I have the following SQL query which works:

```
SELECT 
    h.entidade, h.datadoc, h.tipodoc, h.numdoc,
    (SELECT valortotal -
         (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(l.valorrec), 0) 
          FROM LinhasLiq as l
          INNER JOIN cabliq ON l.IdCabLiq = CabLiq.id
          INNER JOIN Historico ON L.IdHistorico = Historico.id
          WHERE cabliq.DataDoc < '01/05/2015'
            AND historico.id = h.id)) as 'valor pendente',  
    coalesce(documentosCCT.Descricao,'')
+' '+ CASE WHEN h.modulo<>'V' THEN coalesce(documentosVenda.Descricao,'') else'' END 
+' '+  coalesce(h.descricao,'') AS descricaogeral   
FROM 
    Historico h 
LEFT JOIN 
    documentosCCT ON h.TipoDoc = documentosCCT.Documento  
LEFT JOIN 
    documentosVenda ON h.Tipodoc = documentosVenda.Documento
WHERE
    h.entidade = 'ta0141' AND
    (h.tipoentidade = 'C' OR h.tipoentidade = 'F') 
ORDER BY 
    datadoc ASC
```

and this specific expression

```
(select valortotal - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(l.valorrec),0) from LinhasLiq as l
    inner join cabliq on l.IdCabLiq = CabLiq.id
    inner join Historico on L.IdHistorico = Historico.id
    where cabliq.DataDoc < '01/05/2015' and historico.id = h.id)) as 'valor pendente'
```

returns a lot of 0 values, so how can I put this entire expression in a having X > 0 clause, or any other way as long as the rows with this expression = 0 doesn't show?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think it's easier to make my point using a real example

Comment: Using a cte, perhaps?

Comment: Questioning and answering is not for the interacting persons only. It will be there even you don't need it, but it should be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what is your circumstances if it is feasible **try** to make query in single `select` statement instead of multiple
Don't make an alias  `valor pendente` like that should be  `valorpendente`

Now you can use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
-- YOUR QUERY
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE valorpendente > 0
```

Comment: @Caetano glad it help you :)